# 404 onWeb API routes with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, axios, http-status-code-404

I'm stumped by this error.
I have an API controller as follow's

```
using Cousant.InvestNow.Web.Areas.Customer.Models;
using Cousant.InvestNow.Web.Controllers;
using log4net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using TheOakSoft.ApiClient;

namespace Cousant.InvestNow.Web.Areas.Customer.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("customer/api/abl")]
    public class AssetBackedLendingApiController : BaseWebApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("my-loans/{customer_id}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetMyLoans(string customerId)
        {
            return HandleResponseException(response =>
            {
                var apiClient = fluentApiClient.NewGetRequest("investnow", "my-loans").AddQuery("customer_id", $"{customerId}");
                var resp = apiClient.GetResponse();
                response.StatusCode = resp.Success && resp.Data != null ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                response.Content = new ObjectContent<ApiResponse>(resp, GetMediaTypeFormatter());
            });
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("get-loan-detail/{application_id:int}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetLoanDetails(int applicationId)
        {
            return HandleResponseException(response =>
            {              
                var apiClient = fluentApiClient.NewGetRequest("investnow", "get-loan-detail").AddQuery("application_id", $"{applicationId}");
                var resp = apiClient.GetResponse();
                response.StatusCode = resp.Success && resp.Data != null ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                response.Content = new ObjectContent<ApiResponse>(resp, GetMediaTypeFormatter());
            });

        }
    }
}
```

When I call the endpoint from Postman, It works.

but when I try calling the same endpoints from JavaScript, I get a 404 Error every time. I'm working on a legacy application and I've written such endpoint before but why this isn't working is beyond me. Please note that this only happens with endpoints that require parameters. Other endpoints in the same controller work fine as long as no route parameters are being passed. Even POST requests work fine.Just GET request with parameters are the issue.

In my Javascript code, I call the enpoints with Axios

```
getLoanDetails: function () {
    var self = this;
    $.LoadingOverlay("show");
    axios.get('/customer/api/abl/get-loan-detail', {
        params: {
            application_id: 50
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
        })
        .catch(function (error) {

        })
        .then(function () {
            
        });
},

getLoanHistory2: function () {
var self = this;
axios.get('/customer/api/abl/my-loans', {
        params: {
            customer_id: self.customerId
       }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
    })
    .catch(function (error) {

    })
    .then(function () {
    });
}
```

Comment: I've posted the answer. Let me know if you need any additional details.

Comment: Passing the parameters via the url too didn’t work.

Comment: Can you please post the url which is being formed in browser network trace?

Comment: Please find screenshot here https://ibb.co/qDssPnH

Comment: Even more screenshots https://ibb.co/mNfHtVn See the Query String Parameters Section

Comment: Are you sure that you have updated the code as I suggested as in your sceenshots I see query string parameter? Your path should be like /my-loans/046..... Please check my answer and update your code to form the url.

Comment: I've now updated the code correctly same issue persists see here https://ibb.co/DQFYKjQ

Comment: You are coming closer now. At server side, the route is defined as `my-loans/{customer_id}` but the method signature is `GetMyLoans(string customerId)`. The variable parameter customer id should be same at both places. So change in the route as `my-loans/{customerId}`.

Comment: Another point - if you want to work on query string parameter then you can keep the current axios call with params (make sure that name of variable should match) and remove the `/{customer_id}` from route. In that case your route would be `/customer/api/abl/my-loans` and with query parameter is should be `/customer/api/abl/my-loans?customerId=040`

Comment: If it worked then can you give the credit to my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[axios-get](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config)'s params add the parameters as query string

so `axios.get('/user?ID=12345')` is equivalent to

```
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  })
```

Your code has defined the parameter as route not a query parameter so

```
axios.get('/customer/api/abl/get-loan-detail', {
        params: {
            application_id: 50
            }
        })
```

is resolving to `/customer/api/abl/get-loan-detail?application_id=50`instead of `/customer/api/abl/get-loan-detail/50` that's why you are getting 404.

You can create the url as follows

```
axios.get(`/customer/api/abl/my-loans/${self.customerId}`).then
```